# magento 2 zoho crm integration

Tags: magento2

i keep having this error

```
zoho_logger.INFO: getFields Website 0 Response {"code":"INVALID_TOKEN","details":{},"message":"invalid oauth token","status":"error"} 

zoho_logger.INFO: insertRecord Respone {"code":"INVALID_TOKEN","details":{},"message":"invalid oauth token","status":"error"}
 [] []
```

configuration in magento2 magenest zoho crm is well configured

i don't know where is the probleme

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message, your OAuth access token is invalid. When calling Zoho APIs, it is required, but since it is not valid, it throws an error, I suppose.